# Is it possible to pause video recording in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, video-recording

I want to pause the video recording in iOS is it possible to do that using any library or framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Download wwdc 2010 sample source codes from here: https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645 and find the code for AVCamDemo project. its all about video recording, pause and play.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it from AVCam to CameraEngine

```
    #import "CameraEngine.h"


- (void) startPreview
{
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* preview = [[CameraEngine engine] getPreviewLayer];
    [preview removeFromSuperlayer];
    preview.frame = self.cameraView.bounds;
    [[preview connection] setVideoOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    [self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:preview];
}



    - (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] startCapture];
    }

    - (IBAction)pauseRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] pauseCapture];
    }

    - (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] stopCapture];
    }
    - (IBAction)resumeRecording:(id)sender
    {
        [[CameraEngine engine] resumeCapture];
    }
```